# PHPUnit runs in triplicate every time

Tags: phpunit, selenium-rc

This is driving me nuts - every time I run PHPUnit, no matter how many tests there are in my file, it runs through the suite three times. If I have testOne and testTwo, it will run like this:

```
testOne
testTwo
testOne
testTwo
testOne
testTwo
```

If I just have one test, it will run like this:

```
testOne
testOne
testOne
```

I've gone through all of my main, bootstrap, etc files (yes there are a lot!) and can't find anything that would instruct it to run multiple tests, much less explicitly try to launch Firefox more than once.

Using a typical header (this isn't what I always use, but just as an example).

```
<?php
class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("*chrome");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://localhost/");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the issue was - improperly commented-out code in phpunit.xml under the  tag. The  config for Firefox and Chrome was supposed to be nixed, so PHPUnit was interpreting that as a command to run the suite two more times.

For some reason, on my box (10.7.3) only Firefox launches regardless of which browser I tell Selenium to use. But that's for another thread. It hasn't been enough of an issue to bother checking into.